# Proper way of dealing with forEach Ajax calls in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I need to update the data for each object in an array using a for loop and once all the data is captured, run a function. I don't want to mix jQuery in this and do it the proper Angular way of doing

Here is what I am doing,

```
    $scope.units = ['u1', 'u2', 'u3'];
    $scope.data = null;
    //get individual unit data
    $scope.getUnitData = function(unit){
        service.getUnitData(unit).success(function(response){
             $scope.data.push({'id' : response.id , 'value' : response.value});
        });
    };

    $scope.updateAllUnits = function(){
    $scope.data = null ; //remove existing data
    angular.forEach($scope.units,function(val,key){
      $scope.getUnitData(val);
    };
    console.log($scope.data); // Need to show all the data but currently it does not as the for    each loop didn't complete
    };
```

The service is defined as.

```
app.factory('service',function($http){
     return {
        getUnitData : function(unit){
        return $http({
            url : myURL,
            method : 'GET',
            params : {'unit' : unit}
            });
        }

     }

});
```

How do I receive a callback when all the pulling has been done in the for loop ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The result of your `$http(...)` call is a promise. This means you can use [`$q.all`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q) to wait for an array of them to complete.

```
$scope.updateAllUnits = function(){
    $scope.data = null ; //remove existing data
    var promises = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.units,function(val,key){
      promises.push($scope.getUnitData(val));
    });
    $q.all(promises).then(function success(data){
      console.log($scope.data); // Should all be here
    }, function failure(err){
      // Can handle this is we want
    });
};
```

Comment: `promises` in your code is just an array. How does $q know that this array has all the objects ?

Comment: We are pushing promises into it inside the `forEach` which is synchronous. When we call `$q.when` the promises are created, but not resolved (there is still data to come from the server). The `$q.when` waits for this all to complete. I have removed a large chunk of this answer as I realised `$http` already returns a promise.

Comment: Ooh, oops. Very sorry, I've been meaning `$q.all`! I will correct, no more typing without thinking first Andy!

Comment: I will check if it works. Although it is good to know that `$q.when` takes an array of promises. The documentation does not mention that.

Comment: I think `$q.when` will take the array but it will be immediately resolved. I hope that doesn't cause silent hassle for anyone reading the top few comments. Sorry for the brain-fart...